# Why does textView.setTextColor() only support 10 character color names?

Tags: java, android

For example,

```
TextView feedback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);
        feedback.setText("good job!");
        feedback.setTextColor(0xff77dd77);
```

Sets the text color to #77dd77, which I found on this site:
http://www.colorhexa.com/77dd77

Thanks in advance!

Comment: feedback.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("Hex Code"));

Comment: How this is related to android-studio IDE ? I guess AS tag is unrelated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation of [`setTextColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)):

> A color value in the form 0xAARRGGBB.

Where AA - is alpha channel, and `0x` is standing for hexadecimal representation. So The `RGB` part of `0xff77dd77` is `77DD77`
But if you try to pass `0x77DD77` it's actually `0x0077DD77` and the color will be fully invisible.